# Meteor Interaction with JQuery or Animation in General

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

So basically, I'm building an app in Meteor, and I have the left navbar in a `position: fixed;` and `left : -300px` and want to slide it over to `left : 300px`, but have no idea about how to animate a transition in Meteor (somewhat the slide transition in jquery).  I understand the basic JQuery aspect of thing, but for some reason, it doesnt seem to work when I put it under the if Meteor.isClient aspect of the script.  Keep in mind, Im am fairly new to Meteor, inclusive javascript code would be much appreciated.

My current code is as follows.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class='topmenu'>
        <div class='menubutton'>
            <span class="icon-bar1"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar2"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar3"></span>
            <!--Needs to be fixed so that we only need to use one icon-bar class!!!-->
        </div>
        <div class='BanditDiv'>
            <h1 class='BanditName'>Bandit</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='leftnav'>
        <div class='sitenav'>
            <a class='internalnav' href="#">Home</a>
            <a class='internalnav' href="#">Musicians</a>
            <a class='internalnav' href="#">Recording Space</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='main'>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;    
}

.navitem:hover{
    background-color: #000066;
}

.main{
    background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.topmenu{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 2px lightgray solid;
}

.BanditDiv{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30vw;
    margin-left: 35vw;
    float: center;
}

.BanditName{
    text-align: center;
    font: 400 25px/1.3 'Berkshire Swash', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000066;
}

.menubutton{
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px #cccccc solid;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.menubutton:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

.icon-bar1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.icon-bar2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    left: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.icon-bar3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 35px;
    left: 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.leftnav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: -300px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 9001;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: What does your JS currently look like and how is your code behaving at the moment?

Comment: I actually got it to work! It looks like it was because of my lack of use of angular or templates.  Thanks for the concern though!

Comment: If you got it to work please publish your own answer. Your question got upvoted so clearly people are curious about this topic.

Answer (score 3):

So this is what I came up with for the solution that seemed to work.
I created an angular module inside the Meteor.isClient and that seemed to work well.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) { 
  angular.module('sidebar',['angular-meteor']);

  angular.module('sidebar').controller('SidebarCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
      function Menu (callback){
        $('.menubutton').on('click', function (){
          $('.leftnav').css({"box-shadow" : "2px 2px 2px #888888"});
          $('.leftnav').animate({left : "0px"}, 500, function(){
            $('.main').click(function() {
              $('.leftnav').animate({left: "-302px"}, 500);
              $('.leftnav').css({"box-shadow" : "none"});
            });
            $('.leftnav').click(function(event){
              event.stopPropagation();
            }); 
          });
        });    
      }
      Menu();
  }]);
}
```